# What does a solar magnetosphere "short circuit" mean?

Tags: the-sun

I can't understand the last sentence in this text, entirely. 
Please, help me.
Thank you

Comment: Good question, but I think you should find a better title, one that actually describes the question.

Comment: Please give the source of this text.

Comment: In this case, I think the term "short circuit" is inaccurate and I understand your confusion.  I've also seen it described as the magnetic field lines "snapping" leading to the coronal mass ejection.  But neither "snap" nor "short circuit" does a good job of explaining what actually happens (and I'm not sure I should try as I don't have a good grasp of the specifics).  but see here for some explanation:   http://www.space.com/22393-sun-magnetic-field-explained-infographic.html and here a person tries to explain the process.  
"

Comment: Forgot to include the link, but I like this description, because a magnetic field "line" isn't a physical thing, it's a model that explains the magnetic force, there's nothing to "snap", so short circuit is maybe a better term, but still inadequate.    All this said, some of your questions could probably be answered by a bit of google and research, not just posting a page and saying "I don't understand".   Try to formulate specific questions beyond "what does this mean?".   https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/how-can-magnetic-field-lines-snap.394949/

Comment: @userLTK Thanks for your kind. It was very useful to me because I got a hint your comment. I solved my problem due to you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the source of the text was not given.

Answer (score 2):

To understand what's intended, you need to be comfortable with the concept of electromagnetic fields, and the difference between field strength and field gradients.  I think the author is trying to describe the collapse of a magnetic field over a large area into a field over a very small area but with steeper gradients.  At some point in this process, the field gives up energy (which means photons are generated), some of which forces physical particles free of the sun's gravity well.

Comment: Thank you. I got a hint from your explanation, so I could search the information in own my language.